# How to set the Twilio To phoneNumber getting this number as a user input in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, twilio

"I'm implementing a registration mechanism where i have an attribute of phone number in my fields. How do i send a message to this phone number input by the user during registration using Twilio?"

This is for Twilio SMS notification sending to the user when an account has been successfully created. Below is a piece of how my code is implemented.

```
private static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACd176f3083e1333d14939fe6f27d90a99";
private static final String AUTH_ID = "4e3327cb4efbe3ecd8e893d809533763";

public void sendSMS() {
    try {
        User user = new User();
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_ID);

        Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(user.getPhoneNumber()), new PhoneNumber("+12029151841"),
                "Your account has been created succesfuly.").create();

    }
    catch (TwilioException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occured from twillio."+e.getMessage());
    }
}

@PostMapping(value="/registerUser")
public ModelAndView registerUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelAndView modelAndView){

//skipped other is statements for checking possible errors.
else{
        //set a user to disabled by default before activation thru email.
        user.setEnabled(false);

        //save a user in the database.
        userService.save(user);

        //generating the confirmation token

        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = new ConfirmationToken(user);
        confirmationTokenRepository.save(confirmationToken);

        //sending the email message

        SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage =   new     SimpleMailMessage();
        simpleMailMessage.setTo(user.getEmail());
        simpleMailMessage.setSubject("Complete your registrations");
        simpleMailMessage.setFrom("devkibuchi2018@gmail.com");
        simpleMailMessage.setText("To activate your account, please     click here : "
        +"http://localhost:8080/activate-    account?token="+confirmationToken.getConfirmationToken());

        emailSenderService.sendEmail(simpleMailMessage);
        modelAndView.addObject("Email ", user.getEmail());

        //send also an sms message using Twilio.
        sendSMS();

        modelAndView.setViewName("successfulRegistration");

    }

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Thymeleaf segment where a user is inputting the phone number.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/registerUser}" th:object="${user}"  method="post" >
 <div class="form-group">
    <label th:for="phoneNumber">Phone Number: </label>
    <input class="form-control" th:field="*{phoneNumber}" />
    <br>
    <label th:for="phoneNumber" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{phoneNumber}" required="required"
           class="btn btn-danger">
    </label>

</div>
</form>
```

I'm expecting the system to fetch the phone number and set it Twilio To phoneNumber. However, im having this error:

An error occured from twillio.A 'To' phone number is required.

Comment: Hey soo quick to down-vote. I was working on submitting code since it didn't submit. My coke is there above. @SumitBadaya

Comment: Debug your code `user.getPhoneNumber()` 
it must be giving you null. And thats the issue in your code.

Comment: the user object is getting the phone number that  a user is inputting using thyme-leaf form field for phone number. It's no null since it;s being submitted in the database as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User user = new User();
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_ID);

        Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(user.getPhoneNumber())
```

The user object has null phoneNumber as you never set it anywhere in the code.
So you are getting null pointer exception here `user.getPhoneNumber()`

If you write like:

```
User user = new User();
user.setPhoneNumber("+12541254122");
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_ID);

        Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(user.getPhoneNumber()), new PhoneNumber("+12029151841"),
                "Your account has been created succesfuly.").create();
```

then it should work without null pointer exception

---

Below codes will work.

```
public void sendSMS(User user) {
    try {

        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_ID);

        Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(user.getPhoneNumber()), new PhoneNumber("+12029151841"),
                "Your account has been created succesfuly.").create();

    }
    catch (TwilioException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occured from twillio."+e.getMessage());
    }
}

@PostMapping(value="/registerUser")
public ModelAndView registerUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelAndView modelAndView){

//skipped other is statements for checking possible errors.
else{
        //set a user to disabled by default before activation thru email.
        user.setEnabled(false);

        //save a user in the database.
        userService.save(user);

        //generating the confirmation token

        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = new ConfirmationToken(user);
        confirmationTokenRepository.save(confirmationToken);

        //sending the email message

        SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage =   new     SimpleMailMessage();
        simpleMailMessage.setTo(user.getEmail());
        simpleMailMessage.setSubject("Complete your registrations");
        simpleMailMessage.setFrom("devkibuchi2018@gmail.com");
        simpleMailMessage.setText("To activate your account, please     click here : "
        +"http://localhost:8080/activate-    account?token="+confirmationToken.getConfirmationToken());

        emailSenderService.sendEmail(simpleMailMessage);
        modelAndView.addObject("Email ", user.getEmail());

        //send also an sms message using Twilio.
        sendSMS(user);

        modelAndView.setViewName("successfulRegistration");

    }

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: why should it be null and the user is not allowed to submit the form when the phone number field is null?

Comment: It is null because you are creating new `user` object by writing `User user = new User();` and you are not setting any value in any property of it.

I would recommend you to learn the basics first.

Comment: Check my edited answer now. it should work fine. You need to pass your user object in sendsms function rather than creating new user object inside sendsms function.

Comment: Thanks a million.... . It's really working. Oops, i have less than 15 votes bro... i will revisit when i achieve such privilledges